# mysql_query not reciveing full value

Tags: php, mysql

```
$list = array("Apple", "Orange", "Popcorn", "Lemon", "Cola", "Water");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if (isset($_POST[$list[$i]])) {
        $int = $list[$i] . ":";
        echo $int; //the echo here shows all the selected items
    }
}

$u = mysql_query("UPDATE performer_info SET int='$int' WHERE id='$id'"); //the query only gets the last item selected

if (!$u) {
    die("Error : " . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Profile updated";
}
```

so the query only gets the last item selected

```
if $int=Apple:Orange:Lemon:
```

query only gets Lemon:

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Yeah, because you're overwriting `$int` every time.

Comment: do you want `$int = implode(':', $list)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have:

> `$int = $list[$i] . ":";`

Replace it with:

> `$int .= $list[$i] . ":";`

Answer (score 3):

u have to append value in int variable.
but in for loop every time int get assigned new value.

instead of

```
    if(isset($_POST[$list[$i]])) 
    { 
     $int = $list[$i] . ":"; 
     echo $int; 
     }
```

use

```
if(isset($_POST[$list[$i]])) 
 { 
   $int.= $list[$i] . ":"; 
      echo $int; 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Your Code

```
$int = $list[$i] . ":";
```

value for `$int` is overwrite every time when running loop. for appending value for `$int`..

```
$int .= $list[$i] . ":";
```

Thanks